# How to apply a prompt on each retrieved document before answering, in the Langchain ConversationalRetrievalChain

Tags: python, langchain

I am using the ConversationalRetrievalChain to answer a question based on various documents. Since I use large document parts, and to improve the quality of the answer, I first want to summarize each of the top-k retrieved documents based on the question posed, using a prompt.

The code snipped I have is:

```
llm = ChatOpenAI(temperature=0, model = "gpt-3.5-turbo")
question_generator = LLMChain(llm=llm, prompt=CONDENSE_PROMPT)
doc_chain = load_qa_chain(llm, chain_type="stuff", prompt=QA_PROMPT)

chain = ConversationalRetrievalChain(
    retriever=vectorstore.as_retriever(),
    question_generator=question_generator,
    combine_docs_chain=doc_chain)
```

However, I cannot figure out a way to first process the retrieved documents before they are processed by the `load_qa_chain`.

---

For clarity, this would be the prompt I want to use on each retrieved document:

```
intermediate_answer_template = """
You are an AI assistant designed to provide detailed answers.
Given a question and a context, extract any relevant text from the context that addresses the question. 
If the context doesn't provide an answer, respond with "Unknown"

CONTEXT:
{context}

QUESTION: 
{question}

Response in markdown:"""
intermed_ans = PromptTemplate(template=intermediate_answer_template, input_variables=["context", "question"])
```

Comment: you need to override default behavior of load_qa_chain, preprocess the document in call method of ConversationalRetrievalChain

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution. Easiest way is through the ContextualCompressionRetriever() and adding a custom prompt.
For more information see the documentation and examples at:

https://python.langchain.com/docs/modules/data_connection/retrievers/contextual_compression/

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).